# Making org chart in PowerPoint basing on Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to write a project that will create org chart in PowerPoint basing on table in Excel. So, I have a simple table in Excel with two columns: Employee and Reports_to. Something like that

```
Employee    Reports_to
Joe         Eva
Jane        Ann
John        Eva
Eva         Olaf
Ann         Olaf
Bill        Ann
Gilbert     Ann
Olaf
```

Then I have simple function to find all subordinates for any boss:

```
Function GetMinions(sMaster As String) As Collection

Dim rngEmp As Range, cl As Range
Dim collMinions As New Collection

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rngEmp = Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each cl In rngEmp
    If cl.Offset(, 1) = sMaster Then collMinions.Add cl.Value
Next cl

Set GetMinions = collMinions

End Function
```

I also have code that is creating new PowerPoint presentation with one slide and one org chart in this slide. I delete all nodes in this org chart except of the root node. All of that works perfectly, so I don't paste the code. 
And here is my working horse, the macro that build org chart from to to bottom.

```
Sub PopulateOrgChart(nd As Object, str As String)
Dim Minions As Collection
Dim hasMinions As New Collection
Dim it As Object
Dim childNd As Object
Dim i As Integer

Set Minions = GetMinions(str)
For i = 1 To Minions.Count
    Set childNd = nd.Nodes.Add
    Debug.Print nd.Level & "    " & childNd.Level
    childNd.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Minions.item(i)
    If GetMinions(Minions.item(i)).Count > 0 Then hasMinions.Add childNd
Next i

    For i = 1 To hasMinions.Count
    PopulateOrgChart hasMinions(i), hasMinions(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
Next i
End Sub
```

I am running this macro with arguments (smr is defined smartart object):

```
PopulateOrgChart smr.Nodes(1), "Olaf"
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see, Eva and Ann are both in right place as middle-rank managers, all others seems to be OK in third line except of Joe, which is placed just below the top manager. I have tried to figure out what is going on and placed this line after setting the child node:

```
Debug.Print nd.Level & "    " & childNd.Level
```

and my Immediate Window show the same story as my org chart:

```
1    2
1    2
2    2
2    3
2    3
2    3
2    3
```

when adding node for the first subordinate of Eva, it gives the child the same level as for the parent. I am quite confused, as the macro works as expected for all other employees. What I am doing wrong and how could I make Joe subordinate to Eva node, not to the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer after 21 hours. So, I was forced to find roundabout. Not very elegant, but it works. In place of line

```
Set childNd = nd.Nodes.Add
```

I have inserted code:

```
Set childNd = nd.Nodes.Add
If nd.Level = childNd.Level Then
    Set tempNd = childNd
    Set childNd = nd.Nodes.Add
    tempNd.Delete
End If
```

Still, I do not understand why first node added to node is a sibling instead of child.